# How to make only 1 word move with type writer javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make the "initial text" centered, while only the secondary text should be dynamic and moving with the type writer effect.. I don't want to align the text to the left with `text-left`, but rather keep it all in the center and only have the type words move dynamically.

I tried to add `ml-5` but it doesn't have any effect.

I'm using bootstrap and I want this to be also mobile friendly.

```js
// ES6 Class
class TypeWriter {
  constructor(txtElement, words, wait = 3000) {
    this.txtElement = txtElement;
    this.words = words;
    this.txt = '';
    this.wordIndex = 0;
    this.wait = parseInt(wait, 10);
    this.type();
    this.isDeleting = false;
  }

  type() {
    // Current index of word
    const current = this.wordIndex % this.words.length;
    // Get full text of current word
    const fullTxt = this.words[current];

    // Check if deleting
    if(this.isDeleting) {
      // Remove char
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
      // Add char
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    // Insert txt into element
    this.txtElement.innerHTML = `<span class="txt">${this.txt}</span>`;

    // Initial Type Speed
    let typeSpeed = 300;

    if(this.isDeleting) {
      typeSpeed /= 2;
    }

    // If word is complete
    if(!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
      // Make pause at end
      typeSpeed = this.wait;
      // Set delete to true
      this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if(this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
      this.isDeleting = false;
      // Move to next word
      this.wordIndex++;
      // Pause before start typing
      typeSpeed = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(() => this.type(), typeSpeed);
  }
}


// Init On DOM Load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

// Init App
function init() {
  const txtElement = document.querySelector('.txt-type');
  const words = JSON.parse(txtElement.getAttribute('data-words'));
  const wait = txtElement.getAttribute('data-wait');
  // Init TypeWriter
  new TypeWriter(txtElement, words, wait);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400');

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #333 url('https://image.ibb.co/n5A2HU/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #aaa;
}

/* Cursor */
.txt-type > .txt {
  border-right: 0.2rem solid #777;
}
.align-self-baseline {
    align-self: baseline!important
}
@media(min-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center!important
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Welcome To My Site</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">Initial text,
      <span class="txt-type" data-wait="1000" data-words='["Secondary text"]'></span>
    </h3>
  </div>
  
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60115056/9060223) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure CSS approach below*. However, you have to alter a little bit of your HTML to give room for a *placeholder* `Secondary text TextNode`. With the placeholder, we can get the `text-align` not to alter the position of the `Initial text`. Then, we simply alter the real element that is being animated with your typing JS (which has been positioned absolutely from a container that holds both the placeholder and the real element).

I changed your HTML structure a little and added a few lines of CSS:

```js
// ES6 Class
class TypeWriter {
  constructor(txtElement, words, wait = 3000) {
    this.txtElement = txtElement;
    this.words = words;
    this.txt = '';
    this.wordIndex = 0;
    this.wait = parseInt(wait, 10);
    this.type();
    this.isDeleting = false;
  }

  type() {
    // Current index of word
    const current = this.wordIndex % this.words.length;
    // Get full text of current word
    const fullTxt = this.words[current];

    // Check if deleting
    if(this.isDeleting) {
      // Remove char
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
      // Add char
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    // Insert txt into element
    this.txtElement.innerHTML = `<span class="txt">${this.txt}</span>`;

    // Initial Type Speed
    let typeSpeed = 300;

    if(this.isDeleting) {
      typeSpeed /= 2;
    }

    // If word is complete
    if(!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
      // Make pause at end
      typeSpeed = this.wait;
      // Set delete to true
      this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if(this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
      this.isDeleting = false;
      // Move to next word
      this.wordIndex++;
      // Pause before start typing
      typeSpeed = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(() => this.type(), typeSpeed);
  }
}


// Init On DOM Load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

// Init App
function init() {
  const txtElement = document.querySelector('.txt-type');
  const words = JSON.parse(txtElement.getAttribute('data-words'));
  const wait = txtElement.getAttribute('data-wait');
  
  // Init TypeWriter
  new TypeWriter(txtElement, words, wait);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400');

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #333 url('https://image.ibb.co/n5A2HU/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow:hidden;
}

/* =============== */
/* Add starts here */
/* =============== */

.container-type {
    position: relative;
}

.txt-type-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
}

.txt-type {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

/* =============== */
/* Add ends here   */
/* =============== */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #aaa;
}

/* Cursor */
.txt-type > .txt {
  border-right: 0.2rem solid #777;
}
.align-self-baseline {
    align-self: baseline!important
}
@media(min-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center !important
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Welcome To My Site</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">
      Initial text, 
      <!-- Changed here -->
      <span class="container-type">
        <span class="txt-type-placeholder">Secondary text</span>
        <span class="txt-type" data-wait="1000" data-words='["Secondary text"]'></span>
      </span>
      <!-- End of change -->
    </h3>
  </div>
  
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Assuming that the text is always only one line, the above approach works great. However, if there's a chance that the text spans more than one line, do adjust the code so that you create the placeholder such that it is the exact copy of the whole multiple-line text. Then, set the opacity of part of the placeholder text that is not to be animated to 0 and animate away.

Answer (score 1):

as `<span>` is display inline per default it will line up next to initial text, you could just add a `<br>` or set `display:block` to the span element or move it below h2

UPDATE: 
text-align center wont work, align it left with  a dynamic margin to left (using vw)

```js
// ES6 Class
class TypeWriter {
  constructor(txtElement, words, wait = 3000) {
    this.txtElement = txtElement;
    this.words = words;
    this.txt = '';
    this.wordIndex = 0;
    this.wait = parseInt(wait, 10);
    this.type();
    this.isDeleting = false;
  }

  type() {
    // Current index of word
    const current = this.wordIndex % this.words.length;
    // Get full text of current word
    const fullTxt = this.words[current];

    // Check if deleting
    if(this.isDeleting) {
      // Remove char
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
      // Add char
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    // Insert txt into element
    this.txtElement.innerHTML = `<span class="txt">${this.txt}</span>`;

    // Initial Type Speed
    let typeSpeed = 300;

    if(this.isDeleting) {
      typeSpeed /= 2;
    }

    // If word is complete
    if(!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
      // Make pause at end
      typeSpeed = this.wait;
      // Set delete to true
      this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if(this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
      this.isDeleting = false;
      // Move to next word
      this.wordIndex++;
      // Pause before start typing
      typeSpeed = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(() => this.type(), typeSpeed);
  }
}


// Init On DOM Load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

// Init App
function init() {
  const txtElement = document.querySelector('.txt-type');
  const words = JSON.parse(txtElement.getAttribute('data-words'));
  const wait = txtElement.getAttribute('data-wait');
  // Init TypeWriter
  new TypeWriter(txtElement, words, wait);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400');

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #333 url('https://image.ibb.co/n5A2HU/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #aaa;
}

/* Cursor */
.txt-type > .txt {
  border-right: 0.2rem solid #777;
}
.align-self-baseline {
    align-self: baseline!important
}
@media(min-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.text-center {
    margin-left:25vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Welcome To My Site</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">Initial text,
      <span class="txt-type" data-wait="1000" data-words='["Secondary text"]'></span>
    </h3>
  </div>
  
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I want it to be in one line

Comment: ok i didnt understand that, forget my answer then, you cant use text-align center then, because with every character typed it will shift the center of the sentence (initial text moves also) you could try text-align left and add like `margin-left:25vw` and see if that works out

Comment: check my updated answer and play around with the margin-left value

Answer (score 0):

Take a look. There are two copies of the text, one is visible, the other is transparent.

Characters added in the visible span are removed from the transparent span, and characters removed from the visible span are added to the transparent span, so that the total length/width remains unchanged.

```js
// ES6 Class
class TypeWriter {
  constructor(txtElement, words, wait = 3000, fakeElement) {
    this.txtElement = txtElement;
    this.fakeElement = fakeElement;
    this.words = words;
    this.txt = '';
    this.fakeTxt = 'Secondary text';
    this.wordIndex = 0;
    this.wait = parseInt(wait, 10);
    this.type();
    this.isDeleting = false;
  }

  type() {
    // Current index of word
    const current = this.wordIndex % this.words.length;
    // Get full text of current word
    const fullTxt = this.words[current];

    // Check if deleting
    if(this.isDeleting) {
      // Remove char
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
      this.fakeTxt = fullTxt.substring(this.txt.length);
    } else {
      // Add char
      this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
      this.fakeTxt = fullTxt.substring(this.txt.length);
    }

    // Insert txt into element
    this.txtElement.innerHTML = `<span class="txt">${this.txt}</span>`;
    this.fakeElement.innerHTML = `<span class="txt">${this.fakeTxt}</span>`;

    // Initial Type Speed
    let typeSpeed = 300;

    if(this.isDeleting) {
      typeSpeed /= 2;
    }

    // If word is complete
    if(!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
      // Make pause at end
      typeSpeed = this.wait;
      // Set delete to true
      this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if(this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
      this.isDeleting = false;
      // Move to next word
      this.wordIndex++;
      // Pause before start typing
      typeSpeed = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(() => this.type(), typeSpeed);
  }
}


// Init On DOM Load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

// Init App
function init() {
  const txtElement = document.querySelector('.txt-type');
  const words = JSON.parse(txtElement.getAttribute('data-words'));
  const wait = txtElement.getAttribute('data-wait');
  const fakeElement = document.querySelector('.txt-fake');
  // Init TypeWriter
  new TypeWriter(txtElement, words, wait, fakeElement);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400');

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #333 url('https://image.ibb.co/n5A2HU/showcase.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #aaa;
}

/* Cursor */
.txt-type > .txt {
  border-right: 0.2rem solid #777;
}
.align-self-baseline {
    align-self: baseline!important
}
@media(min-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center!important
}
.txt-fake {
    color: #12345600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Welcome To My Site</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">Initial text,
      <span class="txt-type" data-wait="1000" data-words='["Secondary text"]'
      ></span><span class="txt-fake">Secondary text</span></h3>
  </div>
  
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```